# Grep to extract the word matching the given pattern

Tags: shell, unix

I have a log file with entries like

```
INFO 2013-08-16 13:46:48,660 Index=abc:12 insertTotal=11  
INFO 2013-08-16 13:46:48,660 Index=abcd:12 insertTotal=11  
INFO 2013-08-16 13:46:48,660 Index=def:134 insertTotal=11  
INFO 2013-08-16 13:46:48,660 Index=abkfe insertTotal=11
INFO 2013-08-16 13:46:48,660 Index=lmkfe insertTotal=11
INFO 2013-08-16 13:46:48,660 Index=lmkfe insertTotal=11
```

I would like to grep and extract the words that match my pattern which is `abc:<some_number>` and `def:<some_number>`.

```
$ cat "log.txt" | grep -w "abc" -w "def" >> "failed_values.txt";
```

So in this case, my `failed_values.txt` should only have

```
abc:12
def:134
```

The key to note is that my pattern ends with a `:` followed by a number and then a space e. g. `abc:122`.

Comment: Why `abcd:12` is not included?

Comment: Because my suffix just has abc:<some_number>  In other words, in the log file I am searching for John:1212 and Tim:1212 not random letters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try following:

```
$ grep  -Eio '[a-z]+:[0-9]+' log.txt 
abc:12
abcd:12
def:134
```

- `-i` to ignore case.
- `-o` to print only matched part.

**UPDATE**

To match only `abc` / `def`:

```
$ grep  -Eio '\b(abc|def):[0-9]+\b' log.txt 
abc:12
def:134
```

- `(abc|def):`: match `abc` or(|) `def` followed by `:`.
- `[0-9]+`: matched numbers.
- `\b`: match word boundary

Comment: Thanks @falsetru but my prefix is not variable i.e the word will always start with abc:<some_number> or def:<some_number>

Comment: @John, I added an explanation about the pattern used.

Comment: @John, Omit `-i` options if you don't want to match `ABC:123`.

Comment: Thank you @falsetru. Is it possible to have the separator as : or _ so essentially $ grep  -Eio '\b(abc|def)(:/_)[0-9]+\b' log.txt

Comment: @John, Use `[:/_]` instead of `(:/_)`.

Comment: One final question on this. Is it possible to replace [0-9] with a pattern that takes alphanumeric characters?

Comment: @John, Use `[0-9A-Za-z]`. If you use `-i` option, you can used `[0-9a-z]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep -Eo "(abc|def):[0-9]*" log.txt
abc:12
def:134
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

`grep "[ad][be][cf]:[0-9]*" [your file]`