# How to extract particular string from a file (linux)

Tags: linux, parsing, command-line, sed, grep

I have the following file

```
vol-12345678    gp2
vol-89dfg58g
VOLUMES 2016-03-17T22:03:08.374Z  False   100     16      snap-7073d522   in-use  vol-4568gds4    gp2
ATTACHMENTS     2016-03-17T22:03:08.000Z        True    /dev/sda1       i-181ed33c      attached        vol-7ea1c83f
```

etc.

etc.

I want to extract all instances of 'vol-********' and output it to a file (without the other contents) resulting in a file of:

vol-12345678

vol-34556767

vol-34534sdf

...

This is a relatively small file so I could do it manually, but I have another file with 200+ cases. Any idea how to use this using GREP or SED or AWK? Thanks!

Comment: The numbers in the sample output don't seem to match the input data.

Comment: It was just to show an example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grep to extract the word matching the given pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328777/grep-to-extract-the-word-matching-the-given-pattern)

Comment: An output example should *always* match the data.

Comment: I deleted a lot of the data in the original post as it was sensitive info.

Comment: Thats fine but make sure what you leave behind is consistent between the input and output. Don't tell us you want to output X when your input is A B C. It matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE
Command:

```
sed -n 's/.*\b\(vol-[[:alnum:]]*\).*/\1/'p test2
```

Output:

```
vol-12345678
vol-89dfg58g
vol-4568gds4
vol-7ea1c83f
```

Flags:
n : Suppress automatic printing of pattern space.
p : Print out the pattern space

Pattern:

- Look for 'vol-[alphanumeric]s'
- Substitute it and print the first match with \1

More details [Sed](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/used.htm)

Comment: Can you explain what all the flags are after sed? This worked perfectly but i don't understand how it works

Comment: @Dallas That doesn't do what you asked for (try it with a line like "garden voles suck" in your input) and doesn't even produce the expected output shown in your question so why would you accept it?

Comment: It shouldn't work, yet the above code does work given the input data in the OP's first draft, because despite the duplicate 'vol-' numbers, only *one* of every 'vol-' number was followed by a *space*, the others were followed by *'\n'*.   At the minimum, it's an interesting coincidence.

Comment: Agreed it was not a complete solution. Updated command does it now.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
grep -o 'vol-[[:alnum:]]*' input.data | sort -u > output.data
```

Comment: Hmm.  The question doesn't mention duplicates...  but I've now added a `sort -u`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you - I also tried '| uniq' and that worked as well.

Comment: @Dallas the pipe to uniq working is coincidence. Read the man pages for the tools you are using.